# Telling ggplot2 to draw a histogram where no quantitative data is present

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I use the following data set (downloadable [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109495328/WDI_Data.csv)) and the code snippet (in the end of the question) to draw a graph with ggplot2 in R.

If you look at the graph down below, I was wondering if it is possible to draw a histogram of the data in question?

[image]

When I type `ggplot(WDI_Growth_annual, aes(x = gdp_annual)) + geom_histogram()`, I get - of course - the graph, pasted down below. Now, would it be somehow possible to tell ggplot to draw a histogram simply from the points (I have in the first graph) down to the x-axis? Is this even possible?

[image]

This is the code I use:

```
library(ggplot2)
WDI_Growth_annual <- WDI[which(WDI$Series.Name=='GDP growth (annual %)'),]
WDI_GINI_capita <- WDI[which(WDI$Series.Name=='GNI per capita, Atlas method (current US$)'),]
gdp_annual <- as.numeric(as.character(WDI_Growth_annual$Brazil..BRA.))
gdp_annual <- round(gdp_annual, digits = 2)
gdp_annual <- factor(gdp_annual)
time <- as.numeric(as.character(WDI_Growth_annual$Time))
time <- factor(time)
ggplot(WDI_Growth_annual, aes(x = time, y = gdp_annual)) + geom_line(aes(group=1)) + xlab("Years") + ylab("GDP growth (annual %)") + ggtitle("GDP growth (annual %) / Year for Brazil") + theme(text = element_text(family="Palatino", size=11), axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"), axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black")) + ggsave((filename = "gdp_annual_brazil_2.pdf"), scale = 1, width = par("din")[1], height = par("din")[2], units = c("in", "cm", "mm"), dpi = 300, limitsize = TRUE)
```

Comment: OTOH `geom_histogram(stat="identity")` might do the trick

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get `Error en exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : el argumento "env" está ausente, sin valor por omisión` as result. My system language is in Spanish.

Comment: Step 1: Remove the line `gdp_annual <- factor(gdp_annual)`.
Step 2: plot `ggplot(WDI_Growth_annual, aes(x = gdp_annual)) + geom_histogram()`.
Step 3: Go for the glory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and even better **solution** (for my purposes) than posted above by applying the following code `ggplot(WDI_GDP_annual, aes(x = time, y = gdp_annual, fill = time)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + xlab("Years") + ylab("GDP growth (annual %)") + ggtitle("GDP growth (annual %) / Year for Brazil") + theme(text = element_text(family="Palatino", size=11), axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"), axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black")) + ggsave((filename = "gdp_annual_brazil_boxplots.pdf"), scale = 1, width = par("din")[1], height = par("din")[2], units = c("in", "cm", "mm"), dpi = 300, limitsize = TRUE)`, I get the following graph:

[image]